# How can I customize the totals column and rows in an excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am starting to use the Excel data model and pivot tables. I am struggling to produce the results I want for budgeting type tables. Given my very simplified example:

[image]

I had no problem creating the pivot table with sums for each category of income and expense. I used a slicer for year. The problems I have are with the Totals.

1. I want a column grand total which is the sum of income - the sum of expense, but it appears that pivot tables always use the same formula for every value in the table regardless of it being in a totals row or column.
2. In addition to the Total for the year for each row, I would like a monthly average column.

Both these seem to me like obvious things to do with a pivot table. The pivot table makes aggregating all the transactions from the journal trivial. I feel like I must be missing something, because I can't find a way to do something so obviously useful.